# how to install linux OS from iso

Tags: linux, operating-system

Two questions, first question is, I want to start using Linux (the Lubuntu distro) as my operating system. I currently have Windows 7 but I don't want to dual boot or run Lubuntu in a virtual machine (which is what I've been doing).. I want to just uninstall Windows 7 and make Lubuntu my OS. Would I be able to do that with the Lubuntu ISO image file that the developers have on their website?

Second question is, I have a Windows 7 CD (which I used to upgrade from Windows Vista to 7). Once I make Lubuntu my only OS, am I able to switch back to Windows 7 with that CD? Do I just run the installation from the Windows 7 CD?

Comment: Wrong place to ask. http://askubuntu.com/ is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question**; Yes this is possible, you'll want to burn the ISO to a USB stick, then boot from your USB stick. Lubuntu will have an easy installation wizard from the live USB.

[Here's a great guide for it.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#From_Windows)

**Second question**; You will not be able to do it directly with that CD, as having Vista as the main OS is a prerequisite for that CD to work. If you have a Vista installation CD laying around, then you can install that first, then do the Win7 upgrade.

Comment: btw in the link you provided, does the setup of ubuntu as an OS finish , i can't tell if there are multiple ways to install it or if it is giving just one way with multiple steps.. is the Unetbootin just a different method of getting the same task done? or is it the step which I need to complete after the "Linux Live Usb Creator" step? Or does the whole installation process end after "Win32 Disk Imager"?

Comment: Each `<h3>` is a separate method, ie `Linux Live Usb Creator` is the first, `Unetbootin` the second, and so-on. I recommend using the first one, as it is pretty simple.

Be aware this will erase all of your files on your USB, and after you install Lubuntu all of the files on your Windows will be gone as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer for you second question. You can do it.
But I not perfectly understood your first question. Would you like download an .iso file and install system from it?
P. S. Sorry for my English

Comment: His second question is not possible, unless he first installs Windows Vista. The CD he mentioned is just an upgrade from Windows Vista to Windows 7, and it's not possible to upgrade from Linux to Windows 7 with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option of uninstalling windows.

Your best option, if you don't want to use windows anymore is to backup all your data and format the drive. The formating can be done via the ubuntu installer.

Steps:
1. backup all your data from the drive(partition) you will be formating

1. burn the iso to a cd/dvd
2. insert the cd/dvd into the cd/dvd drive and restart your PC
3. select boot from cd/dvd (by default the cd booting is on, but you may have to enable it in bios)
4. install ubuntu(the installation guide will guide you through the process)
5. enjoy Ubuntu

PS: you may want to consider intstalling ubuntu on another partition, this will enable you to choose the OS when you boot your PC

Comment: Hm wait, do I need to backup my data from the partition? Suppose I don't have any files which I want to keep, I don't need to backup the partition then right? Also, "you may want to consider intstalling ubuntu on another partition, this will enable you to choose the OS when you boot your PC".. how do I pick which partition I want lubuntu installed on?

Comment: @user216485 the install guide will ask you, you can choose between using a certain partition, using a whole drive or creating a new partion(when there is some unallocated place on the disk)

Comment: If you don't wish to keep your files, then backup isn't necessary.

Comment: @q99, so what's the difference between using a certain partition, creating a new one or using a whole drive? Would it effect the speed of the OS if I chose one over the other? What differences are there?